# Kivy application window icon

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, ubuntu-18.04, kivy-language

I am running a simple kivy (1.11.1) app on Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS. I am trying to set an icon for my application but nothing seems to be working. I have tried the following so far:

1. Option 1

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy','window_icon','path/to/icon.ico/png')
```

2. Option 2

```
class MyApp(App):
def build(self):
    self.icon = 'myicon.png'
```

None of them worked. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research and realized that the Python logo represents the currently running application. Once the code is compiled and packaged as an Ubuntu package, the icon should change as per expectation. One would have to follow specific packaging instructions for a particular platform. Details are available here:

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging.html

Answer (score 1):

That is an `Ubuntu` question, and is answered [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles).

Comment: I may not have been able to explain clearly or maybe I am missing something. I have created a .desktop file for making a shortcut and changed its icon properly. But when I click on it to launch the main application window, it still shows the Python logo. Any idea on how I can change the same?